# How can I make applescript voice recognition listen for any word?

Tags: applescript, voice-recognition

How can I make applescript voice recognition listen for any word? This is what I have so far:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "c" using {command down}
end tell

tell application "iCal" to activate

tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "n" using {command down}
    keystroke "v" using {command down}
    keystroke return
end tell
```

I would like to substitute the copy on the first line to listen for any words.

Comment: I fail to see how your AppleScript has anything to do with voice recognition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
    set answer to listen for {"yes", "no"} with prompt "prompt"
    --hold the listening key (by default escape) to record an answer
end tell
```

Speakable items have to be enabled first:

[image]
[image]

See http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24662 for more detailed instructions.